# Android NDK: ndk-build script fails - script "check-cygwin-make.mk" not found

Tags: android, cygwin, android-ndk

I'm new to development with the NDK of Android. 
As I'm developing on Win7 I installed Cygwin in order to build the native binaries.

When running **ndk-build** from the project folder **/home/simon/ndk/hello-neon** I get the error

```
ERROR: You are using a non-Cygwin compatible Make program.
Currently using: C:/Programs/cygwin/bin/make

To solve the issue, follow these steps:

1. Ensure that the Cygwin 'make' package is installed.
   NOTE: You will need GNU Make 3.81 or later!

2. Define the GNUMAKE environment variable to point to it, as in:

     export GNUMAKE=/usr/bin/make

3. Call 'ndk-build' again.
```

The problem that stops me now is that the **ndk-build** script seems not to be able to call the **check-cygwin-make.mk** script in the following lines:

```
GNUMAKE=`cygpath -u $GNUMAKE`
PROGDIR_MIXED=`cygpath -m $PROGDIR`
CYGWIN_GNUMAKE=`$GNUMAKE -f "$PROGDIR_MIXED/build/core/check-cygwin-make.mk" 2>&1`
```

When calling

```
echo $CYGWIN_GNUMAKE
```

I get the reply:

```
make: C:/Programs/cygwin/home/simon/build/core/check-cygwin-make.mk: No such fil
e or directory make: AndroidManifest.xml build.properties default.properties jni 
 res src No rule to make target `C:/Programs/cygwin/home/simon/build/core/check-
cygwin-make.mk'. Stop.
```

Now I'm lost because I don't understand the role of the **check-cygwin-make.mk** script and I could not find it anywhere on my drive.

I'm aware of the problem with spaces in the **C:/Program Files/** folder name, and I think this is not problem now.

I hope someone can help my to solve this issue,
Regards,
Simon

Answer (score 0):

Install android-ndk and cygwin(with "make" support command) then set the varaibles like this

```
Right-click My Computer, and then click Properties.
Click the Advanced tab.
Click Environment variables.
then edit"PATH" add this line
```

**C:\cygwin\bin** like this

%SystemRoot%\system32;%SystemRoot%;%SystemRoot%\System32\Wbem;C:\Program Files......;`C:\cygwin\bin`

then try with your built steps

Answer (score 0):

'check-cygwin-make.mk' is in '\android-ndk-r6b\build\core', and you should have installed Android NDK to a directory without spaces in the path.
Next you should be running ndk-build either from Cygwin-shell, or with the command 'bash -c ndk-build'.
And of course the necessary paths both to Cygwin binaries (as in the previous answer), and to ndk-build should be specified in PATH.

Comment: i have android-ndk-r9d and there is no build directory